# Avoid html entities in html_safe method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a problem with my application. I'm trying to add AMP pages and I have the inline stiles in my layout.

```
- if Rails.application.assets && Rails.application.assets['amp/application']
      %style(amp-custom)
        =Rails.application.assets['amp/application'].to_s.html_safe
    - else
      %style(amp-custom)
        =File.read "#{Rails.root}/public#{stylesheet_path('amp/application', host: nil)}"
```

The problem is the output. The source

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'proxima-nova';
  src: url(/assets/proxima_nova_reg-webfont.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This is the result

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'proxima-nova';
src: url(/assets/proxima_nova_reg-webfont.woff) format(&quot;
woff&quot;
);
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal
```

}

Is not validated by amp and is not valid...

Any hint?

Comment: Can't reproduce... Does the generated CSS file in `public/...` look okay? If you put something like `="<br>test</br>".html_safe` in the HAML somewhere, does that work as expected?

Comment: Yes, in my public folder it looks ok!

Comment: Maybe I have to use File.read('pancakes', :encoding => 'iso-8859-1') specifying an encoding?